# What words or phrase can describe the wonder I feel contemplating nature?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I am looking for another word that implies that the world around us is still mysterious, with so much we have yet to discover.

*But I'm not talking about "intelligent design' or creationism*.

Rather I would like to describe the sense of wonder I feel in contemplating  how the planets revolve in their orbits or how all parts of an ecosystem fit together.  These things amaze me; that everything is so "right" and it all works.

Comment: @Mick If I'm reading this right, OP wants to talk about intelligent design in a non-cosmogonic context. I would suggest that in that context there would be no confusion and you can just say "intelligent design"

Comment: @Mick It seems like OP wants to talk about design, presumably of artificial or social constructions, without invoking creation theory,

Comment: @Sallyz Can you give more information about the context?

Comment: Please provide some example sentences in which you would like to use these words.

Comment: ***Creationism***.

Comment: [*Aesthetics*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aesthetic), perhaps?

Comment: @Sallyz Are you trying to point to patterns or precisions in nature without implicitly endorsing creationism?

Comment: Yes, that would describe it.

Comment: I believe that the OP is trying to find a term for the kinds of design principles described in [this article](https://designshack.net/articles/intentional-or-not-mathematical-theory-in-design/)

Comment: @SallyZ Maybe add that to the question so contributors can best understand the question and get on to trying to answer :)

Comment: @Sallyz Creationist argument may be a good source for phrases such as the one you're after. I haven't found one applying as broadly as you need, but "irreducible complexity" and "balance in nature" are not inextricably creationist and nibble at the edges of your case.

Comment: @Sallyz It seems like someone who misunderstood your question edited the question and explanation. You may want to revisit/revise.

Comment: @Sallyz Please also review the [single-word-request tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) to see what's required for these questions.

Comment: @GetzelR I haven't encountered "balance in nature", but "irreducible complexity" is indelibly marked for the creationist agenda. Anyone, on either side of the issue, would, upon hearing it, recognize it as a ID/creationist term. It won't serve to hide OP's creationist agenda, if that is her purpose in asking this question.

Comment: @DanBron I'm assuming benign motives and a non-cosmogonic context. In the context of marveling at the nature world, its attributes and their interactions, phrases that might otherwise indicate creationism. That said, I don't know enough to argue a certain term and haven't suggested one I think works anyways. Just pointing her to a resource. There's got to be some gold in them thar hills.

Comment: @GetzelR I agree the creationists will likely have tried a number of different phrasings and euphemisms in their literature. Likely OP can find something there. Maybe if it's obscure enough, or won't be unsalveagbly political. That said, statistically speaking, giving the way the ID camp operates and evolves (heh), I do imagine OP is seeking a term which will allow her to talk about creationism/ID without using those (by now, loaded) terms. But I could always be wrong.

Comment: @DanBron Can't she just be talking about the amazing aspects of nature without an agenda?

Comment: @GetzelR She could be, of course, but as I said, based on historical examples and statistics, it is less likely than the alternative. Especially since she used the literal term "intelligent design" in her title.

Comment: @DanBron She can just have been trying and meeting resistance because of unintended subtext, which she's tring to avoid. Honestly, it's odd that we can't think of a word/phrase to describe the intricate and effective interplay of parts a complex system.

Comment: @GetzelR As I said, she could be, but my strong suspicion is she is not. And we have plenty of words for them, not least "system", "design", "complexity", and so on, but the issue is most of the obvious ones have already been co-opted by the creationist crowd in their continual quest to rebrand themselves and avoid the strictures the courts have imposed on previous incarnations and labels.

Comment: If you do not wish to imply "Creationism" or some other religious slant, it would be best to substitute some synonym for "intelligent".  For instance, one might say "literate design".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50797/discussion-on-question-by-sallyz-what-other-words-could-be-found-for-intelligent).

Comment: I have extensively edited your question, and maybe violated your intent.  If you disapprove of my edit, either let me know or change it back to your form.  I apologize if I have done too much and changed your question into something you did not want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a word for the feeling itself, 'awe' implies both the sense of wonder but also amazement and uncertainty (if that is what you intend to imply).  You could also use 'reverence' if you want to imply a certain amount of spiritual influence.

To describe the inclination to explore these feelings, not tied to a particular ideology such as intelligent design, one possibility could be 'mysticism'.  Again it has a spiritual leaning without being associated very strongly with one doctrine over another.

Comment: The problem with *awe* is it's not specific to the feelings that one gets from observing the mechanics of the universe as a whole. One can be *in awe* of a great president, for example.

Comment: @DanBron, the fact that it can be used in other situations doesn't mean it can't also be used here.  As far as I know there isn't a word which *exclusively* means awe which is induced by nature, but if you are aware of one I'd be interested to hear it.  The question as worded asks two different things, my suggestion of 'awe' addresses the request for describing the feeling.

Comment: I agree it's applicable, but so is *amazement*, *wonder*, and so on. It's not a wrong answer by any means, it's just too generic, imo.

Comment: I would argue that it's less generic than those two, but the "right" answer partly depends on just how much intelligence of design the OP intends to imply (regardless of my personal opinions on the subject).